# Getting dropdown control out of multiple dropdown controls in a table row using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, tabular

I have this strange scenario.

I have a table having multiple rows (each generated dynamically on click of a button).

Each row has these :

|=======|      |=======|     |=======| 
|=======|

Where |=======| represents a select control (dropdown) in the html page

Now I uniquely want to identify each control, say 1.select1, 1.select2, 1.select3 and 1.select4 for row no.1

The problem is rows might be deleted from the middle. So, I want each select control to have a seperate staring value like x.select1, x.select2, x.select3, x.select4 where x is the unique number.

Is there any way I can access say x.select2 when I click on x.select1 ?

For that I need to uniquely name each set of select controls (in a row).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each `select` is in its own `td`, you can use the [`:eq` selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) to find it:

```
function get_select(tr_idx, td_idx) {
    return $('table tr:eq('+tr_idx+') td:eq('+td_idx+') select');
}
```

If you have a select and want the next one, you can do:

```
function get_next_select(sel) {
    return sel.parent('td').next('td').find('select:first');
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how I can access any the dropdowns in the previous tr? Each control is in a seperate td in a tr. I acually need to get the number (x) in the previous tr so I can name the dropdowns as x+1. I hope I am able to explain it.

Comment: Can you tell me how I can access any the dropdowns in the previous tr? Each control is in a seperate td in a tr. I acually need to get the number (x) in the previous tr so I can name the dropdowns as x+1. I hope I am able to explain it.

Comment: Use `.closest` instead of `.parent` to get to the first ancestor of the element that matches the selector, then do `.prev()` or `.prev('tr')`. Use `sel.parent('td').index()` to get the index of the `td` in its parent `tr`. Use both to get the `select` just above the current `select`.